# JavaScript enable async globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Is it possible to enable async in the global scope? This would be really nice so I don't have to wrap all async stuff in a function. If it isn't possible in browser JavaScript, is it possible in Node.js?

I know I can use a self-executing-anonymous-async-function but to me they look ugly.

```
(async function() {
  // do stuff
})();
```

Just seems so convoluted.
It would be great to just be able to use `await` in the global scope.

Comment: Just put your code inside an async `main` function.

Comment: _"Is it possible..."_ -- No.

Comment: for the browser you can use `<script async src="module.js">`

Comment: @Sysix You misunderstand the question. That loads the script asynchronously. He wants to use `await` without being inside a function (that that function would have to be marked with `async` does not even come into play since he doesn't have one to begin with).

Comment: the reason this is not possible is because `async` changes what a function returns - and using an IIFE doesn't really help anyway, any functions within the IIFE wouldn't magically be tagged `async` anyway

Comment: You can take a look at robert klep's top level await library: https://github.com/robertklep/top-level-await . However it has a few downsides you should be aware of when using this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible.  All `async` functions return a promise.  So, it's a special type of function that has to be used in a special way.

In addition, if you actually follow how `async` and `await` actually work, you would understand why you have to designate a specific type of function in order to use `await` and the interpreter needs to know that ahead of time when creating a function scope.

It really should be no big deal to just create an `async` function wrapper if you want to use `await` at the next level of scope.  Putting lots of important logic at the top level scope just ends up making lots of global symbols anyway so it's generally not the best way to design anyway.